# modify xml using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am starting to learn xml and I am facing a problem. I need to add elements to the xml file so I use this method:

```
function newNode() 
{
    var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("Nodes.xml");

    var nodes = xmlDoc.documentElement;
    var newNode = xmlDoc.createElement('node');
    var newName = xmlDoc.createElement('name');
    var newText = xmlDoc.createTextNode('Start Node');

    newName.appendChild(newText);
    newNode.appendChild(newName);
    xmlDoc.documentElement.appendChild(newNode);

    alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

    return xmlDoc;
}
```

it works fine and the alert shows "Start Node", but when I use the same alert command as in:

```
function z() 
{
    var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("Nodes.xml");
    alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

I get this error:  *Unable to get value of the property 'childNodes': object is null or undefined.*

Answer (score 0):

Could you please send an example of XML file before running your z function ?

With what I can see here, it simply means that there is no "name" node in the document, meaning that getElementsByTagName("name") = [], explaining why getElementsByTagName("name")[0] is undefined.

Comment: the xml file starts with the document element only and I will start adding nodes with newNode(). getElementsByTagName("name")[0] is null when called in z() but it works fine in newNode().

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be that guy, but XML can be easily modified and traversed using a library like jQuery, dojo, mootools, or my recent favorite zepto (if you don't need to support old IE).